# Can clockwork robots have any sensory apparatus other than touch/contact/pressure?

Tags: robots, steampunk

Ignoring the constraints of mechanical computation, what sensory modes are even available to such a robot?

Even in the 21st century artificial odor detection is rather primitive, and we have over a half of a century of solid state electronics under our belt. So I'm assuming "smell" is right out. Hearing also seems problematic as well... while maybe microphones are possible, I suspect that without electronic amplification of some sort, getting a useful signal out of them will be impossible. Is that so?

But the real question, I suppose is this: can the clockwork robot see? It doesn't have to be color vision, it doesn't even have to be proper black-and-white vision. Can it see at all? I'm inclined to guess that there might be some clever mechanism that I can't think of that would allow it. Photography existed long before the advent of even the simplest electronic devices... but used chemical media to fix images to suitably prepared surfaces. I can't figure out a way to turn that into a mechanism where a particular rasterized pixel turns a gear (let alone able to reset and do it again a fraction of a second later). Could a clockwork robot even crudely sense light, the way a cavefish might?

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, the first telephones, the first phonographs and phonograph recorders did not have any electronic amplification whatsoever; they came about half a century before practical electronics. If you do to antiques shops you may find purely [mechanical gramophones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonograph) which are perfectly able to play suitable records quite loud.

Comment: @AlexP Yeh, that's why I wondered if audio is a maybe. But it's right at the very edge of the possible. To sample quickly enough, mechanically we've got to have some little geartrain running really fast, and its own vibrations might drown what little signal we can get. I was mostly interested in the vision aspect of this.

Comment: You don't need to "sample". What you need is a set of suitably tuned blades, which will vibrate by resonance. That's how our own ears work; true, in our ears, the vibration of a hair cell is then transduced into a nervous impulse, but the detection of the signal is mechanical.

Comment: Yeah, you want a totally mechanical video camera, with digitized output for pixels, right?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi "Digitized" in the sense that the output could be read in by a clockwork computer. I'm not sure what mechanical tolerance limits are here... at some point with MEMS or proper nanotech, it might be literally mechanical, but it's long since ceased to be "clockwork" in the sense I intended.

Comment: Is electricity entirely forbidden including in any way in any sensors (the photoelectric properties of selenium  for instance where known in the 1800's) to trip mechanical levers? or failing that how about photochemical reactions, are we allowed to use those?

Comment: We generally think of visual input the way we do because we have access to gobs of "pixels" or any analog equivalent.  But that's only one way to deal with it.  Do you *actually* need a camera in the sense that you and I think of a camera?  There are plenty of systems which have done visual tracking using a single pixel and clever hadware around that pixel.  The output is just different than that of a camera, and the processing of that data is different from, say, GIMP.

Answer (score 6):

**Sound**

This one is easy, you know how a [phonographe](https://www.google.com/search?q=phonographe&rlz=1C1NHXL_enGB711GB711&oq=phongraph&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.11942j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) works, well there you go, all mechanical with no electronic parts, the movement of the stylus for reading from the cylinder & (more pertinently for your purpose) for writing to it  is purely mechanical.

*And if it can hear then with triangulation of two or more ear trumpets we 'might' plausibly claim it can 'see' by constructing a 3D image by echolocation of solid objects in its surroundings.*

**Temperature**

Thermostatic [Bimetal Coil spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimetallic_strip) thermometer, again completely mechanical with no electricity.

[image]

*I'm not sure why you might want it, but if you want it to have a temperature sensor, you can have it.*

**Pressure**

A liquid filled [pressure gauge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_measurement) can be used to measure external air pressure (or else water pressure if submerged), also entirely mechanical & easily interfaced with clockwork.

Of course rather than a tyre pressure gauge I imagine it more along the lines of a combination.

[Pressure altimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altimeter)

[Barometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer)

[Bathometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathometer)

[image]

*Not sure why you'd want that one either but there it is.*

**Gravity**

A finely calibrated [spring scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_scale) with a known weight suspended from it could be used to measure locale gravity, only while the robot is at rest & not moving of course.

A possible use for temperature sensor here, for accurate readings you may need to adjust for the effect of locale temperature on the spring.

[image]

*Why you'd want this sensor escapes me, but I thought of it so here it is anyway*

**Motion (Up / Down & 'Attitude')**

A mechanical [gyroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope) set up that trips mechanical switches in it's casing might be used to tell it which way is up etc // Or a series of pendulums set at different angles // Or you can model a sensor on the inner ear, a hollow sphere with many small button switches covering the entire surface of the interior & a ball inside heavy enough to depress any switch it rests on. You might use all three.

*You might want motion sensors in all its extremities as well as the torso to help give it a sense of what it's 'body' is doing.*

*Unexpected motion will cause these to jiggle & bounce so these might double as shock sensors.*

*Speaking of which.*

**Shock**

There's a whole range of early purely mechanical shock & impact sensors you might use including those used for early bombs, landmines & [seismographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seismometer).

**Time**

It's a clockwork robot right, so that's probably all I need to say for this one.

**North**

A strongly magnetized compass needle, strong enough it can push past & trip small switches?

*Large quantities of ferrous metals can distort a compass reading, so if you want this sensor you're robot shouldn't be made of iron or steel, nautical compasses had brass housings, you can use that.*

**Touch**

An easy one, button switches, spring loaded ones for measuring the force of it's grip, from your question you already have this worked out though.

**Sight**

Early 1840's [fax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax) & [mechanical television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_television) technology look promising but both need electricity.

There are [photomechanical materials](https://scitechdaily.com/tiny-micromotor-is-powered-directly-with-light/) that might be of use but most of them are perhaps a bit esoteric or advanced for a steampunk clockwork robot.

Howsoever, if chemicals are acceptable to you there is early photography, [Heliography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliography), the plates are acid etched & then used to relief print the image, so the plates themselves might be 'read' with a fine needle in much the same way as a phonographe, it's going to have a limited supply of 'sight' & won't be able to use that on the go but it could have still shots of its surroundings.

Exposure time required for each plate is probably in the range of several minutes to a few hours (faster if the light's stronger) so you're not going to get a particularly fast frame rate this way.

*But it would be a lot easier if we can use basic [selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium) photocells.*

Comment: FYI: it's not the first time your multiple edits trigger an auto flag. Please try to make your edits more substantial.

Answer (score 4):

About the only way I can see sight working without some sort of electrical signal is to detect heating caused by focused light.

You do have a few options for detecting the heating - I'd imagine the most responsive would be heating gas in a sealed container and mechanically measuring the pressure it exerts. The timescale would probably not be great, but it would depend on the amount of light. If you're willing to go for some sort of giant-squid eyeball  you might do something

A square meter area in typical daylight conditions has several hundred watts of power, so if you directed a fair chunk of that (say 100 watts) into a one-liter gas chamber (contains roughly a gram of air) you'd double its absolute temperature in a couple of seconds (it takes about a joule of energy to heat a gram of air by one degree). This would provide one extra atmosphere of pressure - a square pressure pad 10cm on a side would measure 1000 newtons of force (enough to lift a grown man!) Since I highly doubt your machinery would need anywhere near that to detect something (one newton is probably plenty) you could detect light with that in a few milliseconds time rather than waiting a few seconds - probably as fast as your gears can react, giving real time (one pixel) vision

The problem comes when you start scaling this down. We talked about one square meter of light, but even the aforementioned giant squid has an eye with a pupil area more like 0.01 square meters, meaning even the ideal situation above would take a fair chunk of a second to register. Worse, indoor areas are nowhere near as brightly lit as that, with a few watts per square meter being considered very well lit, as opposed to the hundreds you'd get outdoors even on a cloudy day. That probably requires more time to register than would be useful.

Multi-pixel, 2D vision? That'll be really tricky. With even a pixel size of 10cm being very borderline, gathering a useful number of them would require an absolute leviathan of a clockwork beast. (If you are building an absolute leviathan, problem solved!) About the only way I see you being able to scale these pixels down to a more usable size is if your creature lived very slowly, collecting light not by having a large area, but by waiting a long time to gather it.

TL,DR: Cave fish vision is doable if you are willing to pick two of large eyes, slow response time and restriction to broad daylight. Any remotely detailed vision is probably not doable by purely clockpunk means unless the creature is very large and lives in slow motion.

All this assumes we stay purely mechanical - you could go the route of having actual living creatures in the eye that do something in response to light, along the lines of the Terry Pratchett cameras which have an imp inside them drawing very fast - but I don't know nearly enough about animal behaviour to comment on that one!

Answer (score 3):

A bi-metal mechanical switch  reacts to heat.
So you could focus light with a lens and heat the switch that way.
It would be very crude, and easily disturbed by changes in ambient temperature, but in theory it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Photossensitive resins have been known for a long while. So have lenses.

A couple moving lens and a round chamber can simulate an eye. A honeycomb structure at the back of the eye simulates a retina. The change of pressure caused by the resin shrinking/expanding or softening/hardwning transmits a signal to a series of springs, one per pixel.

There you have it, now you can process it with perforated cards for facial recognition.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try to implement is something purely mechanical:

- the light hits one of two springs
- the increased temperature on the light hit spring causes the two springs to change configuration
- the configuration change triggers some mechanism to start the signal "I am detecting light"

It's a really crude mechanism, but I think it's the best you can get with something solely mechanical.